# See if SKShapeNode touched?: How to Identify node?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am doing a small for fun project in Swift Xcode 6. The function thecircle() is called at a certain rate by a timer in didMoveToView(). My question is how do I detect if any one of the multiple circle nodes on the display is tapped? I currently do not see a way to access a single node in this function.

```
func thecircle() {
    let circlenode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
    circlenode.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    circlenode.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let initialx = CGFloat(20) 
    let initialy = CGFloat(1015)

    let initialposition = CGPoint(x: initialx, y: initialy)
    circlenode.position = initialposition

    self.addChild(circlenode)

    let action1 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: initialx, y: -20), duration: NSTimeInterval(5)) 
    let action2 = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    circlenode.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action1, action2]))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with this.

1. You shouldnt be creating any looping timer in your games.  A scene comes with an `update` method that is called at every frame of the game.  Most of the time this is where you will be checking for changes in your scene.
2. You have no way of accessing `circlenode` from outside of your `thecircle` method.  If you want to access from somewhere else you need to set up circlenode to be a property of your scene.

   For example:

   ```
   class GameScene: BaseScene {
       let circlenode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
   ```
3. You need to use the method `touchesBegan`.  It should have come with your spritekit project.  You can detect a touch to your node the following way:

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

      for touch: AnyObject in touches {

          // detect touch in the scene
         let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

         // check if circlenode has been touched
         if self.circlenode.containsPoint(location) {
               // your code here
         }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Cool! Put this in my code, but one problem. One circle shows up like it should, but when it goes to add the next, it throws me an error: <Attemped to add sknode which already has a parent>. I tried `circlenode.removeFromParent()` but that makes it so only one node completes what it should. No other nodes are then shown. Any ideas?

Comment: you are adding the same circlenode twice.  if you want to add a new circlenode everytime you touch the screen, you need to create a new circlenode everytime you touch the screen..

Comment: So how would I do that? An array of nodes?? If anyone has some snippets of code that would be great! Thanks so much for the help so far

Comment: you just make a new one when they touch the screen.  just create a new circlenode, position it at the touch location and add it to the scene..

Comment: I dont know how to make a new circlenode if "circlenode" already exists

Comment: you aren't really being clear about what you want to accomplish.  if you want a new sprite, make a new sprite.  If you want to keep track of a group of sprites then you can add them to an array.